# Separate Clickonce files

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment, clickonce

I am going through a very quick deployment application cycle with a system. Trouble is I'm using DevExpress dll's which are altogether creating a large and very slow upload. The system is around 60mb now and taking around 30 mins per upload. This is obviously causing me a bottleneck.
Is it possible to put these dll's into a separate upload and my main system to know reference them as a presrequiste?
Any pointers would be gratefully accepted. Thanks Scott

Comment: DevExpress dll's a lot of times have many dependancies that ClickOnce picks up but may not actually be used by your application.  I was able to exclude a few of there dll's from my application as they were never really used, their VerticalGrid is a perfect example.  They may help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Scott. I had figure that out as all the themes added themselves even when not used. I have reduce as much as I can. Seems like bloat but there you go. Cheers! Scott